# Partial search in HashMap

Tags: java, dictionary, filtering

I need to create phone book kind of thing. It contains name & number. Now when I type letters matching list should be returned. For the example given below, when I type H, a list containing Harmer, Harris, Hawken, Hosler should be returned. When type Ha then list containing only Harmer, Harris, Hawken should be returned.

```
  Map<String, String> nameNum = new HashMap<String, String>();

  nameNum.put("Brown", "+1236389023");
  nameNum.put("Bob", "+1236389023");
  nameNum.put("Harmer", "+1236389023");
  nameNum.put("Harris", "+1236389023");
  nameNum.put("Hawken", "+1236389023");
  nameNum.put("Hosler", "+1236389023");
```

Any idea how achieve it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that using a `HashMap` at all is a good idea for something like this? I think a different data structure might be better.

Comment: Are you only looking for the first letter or is it eliminating the list as you type? For example does an input of "Ha" eliminate "Hosler"?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yeah, a HashMap is not the right data structure for this. As Bozho said, a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) would be the right one.

With Java's on-board tools, a TreeMap (or any [SortedMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/SortedMap.html), actually) could be used:

```
public <V> SortedMap<String, V> filterPrefix(SortedMap<String,V> baseMap, String prefix) {
    if(prefix.length() > 0) {
        char nextLetter = prefix.charAt(prefix.length() -1) + 1;
        String end = prefix.substring(0, prefix.length()-1) + nextLetter;
        return baseMap.subMap(prefix, end);
    }
    return baseMap;
}
```

The output would even be sorted by key.

Here an usage example:

```
SortedMap<String, String> nameNum = new TreeMap<String, String>();
// put your phone numbers

String prefix = ...;
for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : filterPrefix(nameNum, prefix).entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry);
}
```

If you want your prefix filter to not be depending on case differences, use a suitable Comparator for your map (like a `Collator` with a suitable strength setting, or `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`).

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann : Why Trie, how does it save space {http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265476/trie-saves-space-but-how} ?

Comment: You can use prefix + "\uffff" as end, also.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann I've the same scenario. But the existing map is a HashMap implementation (for 10k+ elements) and it can't be altered. Now, for achieving this as per the above solution, if I go for dumping the whole thing contained in Hashmap into the TreeMap, the construction of TreeMap itself will be very costly (as it builds a sorted structure), rest might be easy and fast. Any suggestions for wraping this solution on my requirements?

Comment: @abksrv If this is just one search, a single iteration over all entries of your HashMap should be fastest. If you want to do it more often, transfer the data to a better structure. (Also, measure: maybe for your data set and hardware no optimization is even necessary.)

Answer (score 11):

This calls for a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623892/where-do-i-find-a-standard-trie-based-map-implementation-in-java) for java implementations. I used [this one](http://code.google.com/p/patricia-trie/).

Comment: Thanks Bozho your link was useful! But its almost 3 years since that question was answered. Are there any better solutions now, that you may be aware of ?

Comment: link is broken again Bozho

Answer (score 2):

Remove all values which doesn't contain key part:

```
yourMap.keySet().removeIf(key -> !key.contains(keyPart));
```

Or regex:

```
yourMap.keySet().removeIf(key -> !key.matches(".*keyPart.*"));
```

Or filter stream and collect to a new map:

```
yourMap.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getKey().contains(keyPart)).collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it all in a MultiMap (or just store a List as the value in your HashMap). For "Brown", store:

```
"B"->["Brown"]
"BR"->["Brown"]
"BRO"->["Brown"]
```

If you later add "Bradley":

```
"B"->["Brown", "Bradley"]
"BR"->["Brown", "Bradley"]
"BRO"->["Brown"]
"BRA"->["Bradley"]
```

etc...

then have another map to map "Brown" or "Bradley" to the phone number.

Comment: Adding and removing things from this data structure would be *very* costly.

Comment: I agree. But we don't even know how big his "phone book kind of thing" is. I prefer to do something simple first and optimize later. This seems like the simplest thing to do.

Comment: Accesses would be O(1) whereas for the trees it would be log(n). And isn't that more important if you're doing something like autocomplete? And how often is the dataset being updated? If gets are much more frequent that sets, who cares how slow adding/removing is. And adding and removing here is not even that bad I don't think.

Answer (score -2):

Use [guava Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/index.html) will ease your solution.

The key is first letter of name, the value is a `Collection` containing all name-phone pair which name is started with the key(first letter).

Example:

```
    public void test(){
      //firstLetter -> list of name-phone pair
      Multimap<String, Pair> mMap =  ArrayListMultimap.create();

      put(mMap, "Brown",  "+1236389023");
      put(mMap, "Bob",    "+1236389023");
      put(mMap, "Harmer", "+1236389023");
      put(mMap, "Harris", "+1236389023");
      put(mMap, "Hawken", "+1236389023");
      put(mMap, "Hosler", "+1236389023");

      //Test
      System.out.println(mMap.get("H"));
   }

   void put(Multimap<String, Pair> mMap, String name, String phone){
      mMap.put(name.substring(0,1), new Pair(name, phone));
   }

   public static class Pair{
      String name;
      String phone;

      public Pair(String name, String phone) {
         this.name = name;
         this.phone = phone;
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
         return "Pair [name="+name+", phone="+phone+"]";
      }
```

}