# Returning a list of wildcard matches from a HashMap in java

Tags: java, string, hashmap, wildcard

I have a Hashmap which may contain wildcards (*) in the String.

For instance,

```
HashMap<String, Student> students_;
```

can have John* as one key.  I want to know if JohnSmith matches any elements in students_.  There could be several matches for my string (John*, Jo*Smith, etc).  Is there any way I can get a list of these matches from my HashMap?

Is there another object I could be using that does not require me to iterate through every element in my collection, or do I have to suck it up and use a List object?

FYI, my collection will have less than 200 elements in it, and ultimately I will want to find the pair that matches with the least amount of wildcards.

Comment: Hashing functions in general are constructed in a way that minor changes (eg: `John SmitH` to `John Smith`) yield totally different hashes.

Comment: Why don't you want to iterate? It's not that bad (especially with less than 200 elements) , and ultimately any other solution will likely involve something similar in terms of performance.

Comment: At less than 200 elements, just do linear search over `entrySet()` and evaluate your wildcard against each key. If it would have been much more, I'd suggested an (embedded) database and a `LIKE` query.

Comment: Thank you guys.  The list is not huge but I may have to do the get frequently.  I was curious if there was was a more efficient way do this but perhaps not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Partial search in HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713239/partial-search-in-hashmap)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to achieve with a hasmap, because of the hashing function. It would have to assign the hash of `"John*"` and the hash of `"John Smith"` et al. the same value.

You could make it with a TreeMap, if you write your own custom class `WildcardString` wrapping String, and implement `compareTo` in such a way that `"John*".compareTo("John Smith")` returns 0. You could do this with regular expressions like [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610689/returning-a-list-of-wildcard-matches-from-a-hashmap-in-java/7610791#7610791) have already pointed out.

Seeing that you want the *list of widlcard matchings* you could always remove entries as you find them, and iterate `TreeMap.get()`'s. Remember to put the keys back once finished with a name.

This is just a possible way to achieve it. With less than 200 elements you'll be fine iterating.

**UPDATE:** To impose order correctly on the `TreeSet`, you could differentiate the case of comparing two `WildcardString`s (meaning it's a comparation between keys) and comparing a `WildcardString` to a `String` (comparing a key with a search value).

Comment: Thank you, Xavi.  For a list of 200 do you think there will be any performance benefit to using a TreeSet?

Comment: Creating a compareTo(string) method in the WildCardString class would break the contract of the compareTo method because: `wildCardString.compareTo(string)` may not be the opposite sign or `string.compareTo(wildCardString)`. Additionally it's recommended that compareTo is consistent with equals.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to match, but you must first turn `"John*"` into the regex equivalent `"John.*"`, although you can do that on-the-fly.

Here's some code that will work:

```
String name = "John Smith"; // For example
Map<String, Student> students_ = new HashMap<String, Sandbox.Student>();

for (Map.Entry<String, Student> entry : students_.entrySet()) {
    // If the entry key is "John*", this code will match if name = "John Smith"
    if (name.matches("^.*" + entry.getKey().replace("*", ".*") + ".*$")) {
        // do something with the matching map entry
        System.out.println("Student " + entry.getValue() + " matched " + entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

Comment: @Guillaume no he specifically did **NOT** say that. Specifically, he said: *Is there another object I could be using that does not require me to iterate through every element in my collection, **or do I have to suck it up and use a List object** ?*. I answered the question by confirming the *OR* part.

Comment: Bohemian, you sophist :-) I agree with your answer anyway. I don't see why he doesn't want to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate your Map without converting it into a list, and use the String matches function, wih uses a regexp.

If you want to avoid the loop, you can use guava like this

```
@Test
public void hashsetContainsWithWildcards() throws Exception {
Set<String> students = new HashSet<String>();
students.add("John*");
students.add("Jo*Smith");
students.add("Bill");

Set<String> filteredStudents = Sets.filter(students, new Predicate<String>() {
  public boolean apply(String string) {
    return "JohnSmith".matches(string.replace("*", ".*"));
  }
});

assertEquals(2, filteredStudents.size());
assertTrue(filteredStudents.contains("John*"));
assertTrue(filteredStudents.contains("Jo*Smith"));
```

}