# search previous closest date/string in (hash)map

Tags: java, data-structures, dictionary

I've run into a problem where I need to probably redesign my data-structure.

Right now I have lots of info in chronological order and keeping it in Hashmap with key being the `date` that is also a member of `new Info()`.

`hashMap.put(date.toString(), new Info(date, ...))`

dates are with 5 minutes interval

> `2012-02-15 22:45:00.0`
>   `2012-02-15 22:50:00.0`
>   `2012-02-15 22:55:00.0`
>   `2012-02-15 23:00:00.0`
>   ...
>   `2012-02-25 12:10:00.0`
>   `2012-02-25 12:15:00.0`

So far it was easy to get info by getting the key and the **speed is constant time**
`hashMap.get(date.toString())`

So far so good when i'm getting the date from hashmap that is there. But now there could be gaps in info chronological order. In the example below there is missing `2012-02-15 22:50:00.0` so when searching for that date i'd get NPE.
In that case I must find the **previous** closest time.

> `2012-02-15 22:45:00.0`
>   `2012-02-15 22:55:00.0`
>   `2012-02-15 23:00:00.0` 
>   ...

```
if (hashMap.get(date.toString()) != null) {
   // found it
} else {
   return previousTime(date.toString())
}
```

I could make a LinkedHashMap and `previousTime` could just [iterate over the collection](http://www.java-examples.com/iterate-through-values-java-linkedhashmap-example) until i find the closest previous date. But the worst case would be O(n) complexity.
Could there be a better data structure for that kind of task or just use LinkedHashMap? A SortedMap like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713239/partial-search-in-hashmap)? But the initial `put` would be costly and it will take more memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds to me like a [NavigableMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) such as `TreeMap` is exactly what you're looking for.  Though you really shouldn't be using the `String` form of a date as your keys... use the `Date` itself.

Comment: Thank you. I used that and `lowerKey()` works and finds previous date easily

Answer (score 0):

> But the worst case would be O(n) complexity

How big would this n be? I don't think it's a problem even if it's a million. More than that might be a problem though, but before you worry about speed I guess you'll run out of memory first. Simply do backward iteration of each 5 minutes from the point where the asked date isn't found.

Comment: n would be up to 100k. `Simply do backward iteration of each 5 minutes from the point where the asked date isn't found.` but how can i get in hashmap to the point where the asked date is not found? the key/values are hashed and they are not in precise order

Comment: yes, but you know that they're in 5 minutes range. just loop while `get` returns null.