# How to get suggested contact list from for a given name

Tags: android, android-contacts

I`m currently developing an android app for my university project. Idea was to develop an voice command base caller app.  by now i could implement this app to get voice name and retrieve contacts from the contact list. But this only work if i only gives the correct voice input for the voice.So I planed to give suggestions form the contact list from the phone according to the voice input to my app. How can i do that?

```
    package com.chamika_kasun.voicerecognitionapp;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    //import java.util.List;

    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.ContactsContract;
    import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ContentResolver;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    //import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
    import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;

    public class MakeCall extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

        public ListView mList;
        public Button speakButton;

        public static final int VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.make_call);

            speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);
            speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            voiceinputbuttons();

            // Check to see if a recognition activity is present
            // if running on AVD virtual device it will give this message. The mic
            // required only works on an actual android device
              // Disable button if no recognition service is present
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
            if (activities.size() == 0)
            {
                speakButton.setEnabled(false);
                speakButton.setText("Recognizer not present");
            }

        }


        public void voiceinputbuttons() {
            speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);
            mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        }

        public void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {

            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,"Speech recognition demo");
            startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);

        }

        public void onClick(View v) {

            startVoiceRecognitionActivity();

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Fill the list view with the strings the recognizer thought it
                // could have heard
                ArrayList matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                mList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, matches));

                //if (matches.contains("vidudaya")) {

                    String name = matches.toString();
                    String number = "";


                    Toast.makeText(this, "Name : "+name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        "DISPLAY_NAME = '" + name + "'", null, null);
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        String contactId =
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                        //
                        //  Get all phone numbers.
                        //
                        Cursor phones = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                            Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
                        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                           number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
    //                      int type = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
    //                      switch (type) {
    //                          case Phone.TYPE_HOME:
    //                              // do something with the Home number here...
    //                              break;
    //                          case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
    //                              // do something with the Mobile number here...
    //                              break;
    //                          case Phone.TYPE_WORK:
    //                              // do something with the Work number here...
    //                              break;
    //                          }

                            Toast.makeText(this, "My Mobile Number : "+number,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                        phones.close();
                       }
                       cursor.close();

                        String url = "tel:"+number;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url));
                        startActivity(intent);

                //}


                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a reverse index (by letter or N-Gram) from your contact list and query on it after receive the user command.

You can do something like the suggestion on that best answer:

[Partial search in HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713239/partial-search-in-hashmap)