# Android AutoCompleteTextView behaving very slow

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

I have a list of about 250 thousand strings, which I supply into an `AutoCompleteTextView`.

When I apply them to the view, the suggestions popup takes about 10-20 seconds to show.

Since all of the values are at least 10 characters long, I also tried setting the threshold to 5 but it didn't seem to help much.

The code which I used:

```
List<String> locations = GetLocations();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, locations);
((AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_location)).setAdapter(adapter);
((AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_location)).setThreshold(5);
```

**Is there any way to make this behavior faster, or am I missing another alternative approach to this case?**

Edit:
now that I've searched a bit more, seems like there's no other option but to implement a better logic by myself ([How can I speed up an AutocompleteTextView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645239/how-can-i-speed-up-an-autocompletetextview-in-android))

Comment: 250 thousand??? oh my god,  are you serious?

Comment: place all your data in sqlite db,  make sure it has an index for fast data access,  then use SimpleCursorAdapter as your ACTV adapter

Comment: also you can use full text search for searching in the entire document http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html