# Get key from HashMap that contains string fragment

Tags: java, hashmap

What is the easiest way to get `String` `Key` from `HashMap` that contains some String fragment? Is true that only way is enumerate all keys and do `substring()`?

This pseudo code gets exact string, and I need string that only contains fragment.

```
Map hm= new HashMap();
...
res = hm.get("blabla");
```

I need to use java 1.4

Comment: A-B problem. Better tell why do you need it.

Comment: if you can use Common Collections, you may try http://tostring.me/287/partial-string-search-in-hashmap-key/, check also this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713239/partial-search-in-hashmap

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to loop on all keys and search the substring you want.

[HashMap.get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get(java.lang.Object)) will call `equals`, so for Strings, they must have the exact same content.

Answer (score 1):

You have to either create a custom Data Structure or check each key individualy. The following returns a list:

```
Set ref = hm.keySet();
Iterator it = ref.iterator();
List list = new ArrayList(); // list contaning the deired elements

while (it.hasNext()) {
    Object o = it.next(); 
    if(hm.get(o).contains(value)) { 
        list.add(o); 
    } 
}
```