# java string and hashset-membership matching

Tags: java, string, hashset

I am converting single Chinese characters into roman letters(pinyin) using package pinyin4j in java. However, this will often yield multiple pinyins for one character(same character has different pronunciations). Say,character C1 converts to 2 pinyin forms p1 and p2, character C2 converts to 3 pinyin forms, q1,q2,q3.

When I combine C1C2 into a word, it yields 2*3=6 combinations. Usually only one of these is a real word. I want to check these combinations against a lexicon text file I built, with many lines start with \w that is a lexical entry(so for instance, only p1q2 out of the 6 combinations is found in the lexicon). i'm thinking about reading the lexicon file into a hashset. However I'm not sure about how to best implement this whole process. Any suggestions?

Comment: HashSet should work fine.  If you know the size of the lexicon (entries), pre-allocate the HashSet with sufficient capacity so it does not have to be enlarged during loading, to save time.  If the lexicon is huge you might need to investigate a multi-level data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HashSet seems quite alright. If the lexicon is extra large and you have to be super fast, consider using Trie data structure. There is, however, [no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983906/is-there-a-trie-in-java) implementation in the Java.