# Any trie implementation in java( with maven repo )

Tags: java, maven, trie

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623892/where-do-i-find-a-standard-trie-based-map-implementation-in-java), there seems to be a Patricia Trie implementation, but there is no maven repo for it. In any case I can't find the trie in Gauva/Google Collections.
Does anyone know any Trie implementation library in java, that has a maven repo?

**Note**: Its basically to create a backend for an autocomplete feature in frontend. Anything else that helps achieve this should be good enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out [concurrent-trees](http://code.google.com/p/concurrent-trees/), which contains a [concurrent Radix Tree/Patricia Trie](http://concurrent-trees.googlecode.com/svn/concurrent-trees/javadoc/apidocs/com/googlecode/concurrenttrees/radix/ConcurrentRadixTree.html) implementation. It also has published artifacts to the standard [maven repo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.concurrent-trees/concurrent-trees/1.0.0).

Comment: Do you know the name of the class for Trie?

Comment: Updated the answer with a link to the Radix Tree (which is the same as a Patricia Tree - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree)

Answer (score 1):

[org.apache.commons.collections4.trie.PatriciaTrie](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/trie/PatriciaTrie.html)