# which datastructure Or algorithm to use to arrange data of dictionary for sequence search?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, dictionary

I have a dictionary with near around a million words. I have to design algorithm for quick search of sequence of characters.

For ex. if user types `and` the app must return words having the sequence like `random`,`sand`,`stand`
 ...etc.

The existing solution I have is to search for matching regex in all the existing words which is not efficient.
I am open to restructure existing database, caching of dictionary or work at any level if required Or is there some ready made api in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try using a trie ([Where do I find a standard Trie based map implementation in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623892/where-do-i-find-a-standard-trie-based-map-implementation-in-java)).
Using an in memory lucene index may also fit the bill, depending on your requirements

Answer (score 3):

http://lucene.apache.org/core/

Look at this, this should cater to your requirements.

```
final File INDEX_DIR = new File("index");  
try{  
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();  
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test", "root", "password");  
    StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();  
    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(INDEX_DIR, analyzer, true);  
    System.out.println("Indexing to directory '" + INDEX_DIR + "'...");  
    indexDocs(writer, conn);  
    writer.optimize();  
    writer.close();  
} catch (Exception e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}  

void indexDocs(IndexWriter writer, Connection conn) throws Exception {  
String sql = "select id, name, color from pet";  
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();  
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);  
while (rs.next()) {  
    Document d = new Document();  
    d.add(new Field("id", rs.getString("id"), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO));  
    d.add(new Field("name", rs.getString("name"), Field.Store.NO,  Field.Index.TOKENIZED));  
    d.add(new Field("address", rs.getString("address"),Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.TOKENIZED));  
    writer.addDocument(d);  
  }  
}
```

Comment: This directs for having lucene set up , any suggestion of design of db or classes.

Comment: Well design of DB is upto you, what you want to index, should be a flattened structure. For building the index, its like, reading the resultset and adding to Index. Say you want to add three columns for a record to index, you can do something like: