# Java best way to perform String startsWith

Tags: java, string, tree, trie

I want to compare if a provided string starts with any of the strings in an array. The easiest solution being:

```
String b = ...;
boolean matched = false;
for (String a : array) {
  if (b.startsWith(a))
    match = true;
}
```

However, intuitively, I want to use something like a trie to get better efficiency since the array of strings might grow to be pretty big and I need to run these matches fast. I can guarantee that these strings are all alphabetical. I can also guarantee that all strings in the array are length 2 or less. What's the best way to implement this trie-like structure in Java? I couldn't find any Java-based libraries that does this.

Thanks!

Comment: You might look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623892/where-do-i-find-a-standard-trie-based-map-implementation-in-java  or this  https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=8787521

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to insert the strings into a `Set<String>` and then perform two lookups on it, one with the first character of `b` and then if not match with the first two characters of `b`.

For example,

```java
class StartsWithAny {
    private Set<String> set;

    public StartsWithAny(String[] array) {
        set = new HashSet<String>();
        for (String a : array) {
            set.add(a);
        }
    }

    // returns true if b starts with any strings contained in array
    // with the condition that b.length() <= 2
    public boolean startsWithAny(final String b) {
        if (b.length() > 0 && set.contains(b.substring(0, 1))) {
            return true;
        }

        if (b.length() > 1 && set.contains(b.substring(0, 2))) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

A variation on this would be to utilize two separate `Set`s, one for the single character lookup and one for the two character lookup which would improve performance a bit.

An alternative but similar approach would be to implement a binary search algorithm that would operate on the sorted array and perform a similar function.

Comment: I actually ended up simply using a TreeSet and doing a contains() lookup, not sure if that's significantly slower/faster than doing separate lookups, but it's only 2 characters, so it shouldn't be that much different I think.. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 5):

If you truly have enough start strings that it becomes a bottleneck, a trie might indeed help.

This question has been asked and answered on this very site: [Where do I find a standard Trie based map implementation in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623892/where-do-i-find-a-standard-trie-based-map-implementation-in-java)

And this was the answer:   https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=8787521

Comment: Thanks for the links, I remember looking at the post and not seeing a standard implementation. I ended up just using a regular TreeSet and will profile the performance first before getting other libraries. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

> I want to compare if a provided string starts with any of the strings
>   in an array.

Well - you can certainly improve on your current solution :

```
static boolean startsAny(final String b) {
    for (String a : array) {
        if (b.startsWith(a)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

You can use [String#matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) with a regular expression, but I'm not sure this is more efficient.  Have you profiled the code and identified this as a bottleneck?

Comment: Good question about profiling first, and this is faster (but won't compile - it needs a final `return false`).

Comment: Good suggestion on profiling.. It's possible that I am optimizing too early, I'll run some tests and see.