# Java - store objects in a hierarchy that follows their class inheritance

Tags: java

I need to store lots of objects that belong to different classes:

```
ClassA {...}
ClassA1 extends ClassA {...}
ClassA2 extends ClassA {...}
ClassA2a extends ClassA2 {...}
ClassB {...}
```

Now I need to find a way to store all these objects in a way that allows me to **efficiently** get all objects that belong to a particular class and its <strike>inherited</strike> child classes. For example, this imaginary code

```
getObjects(ClassA2)
```

would return a list of all stored objects that belong to ClassA2 or ClassA2a.

I believe a tree collection of some sort would be suitable, but I can't think of any way to implement it. Any ideas?

---

(Background: I am creating a simple java game, in which there's number of sprites that I need to manage, while some of those sprites share similar properties. When I check for events like collisions, I need to get all objects that extend EnemySprite and compare their coordinates with the player's sprite.)

Comment: What is `Class1:ChildClass2` supposed to signify?

Comment: All objects of type ChildClass2 (extends Class1). I'll try to write it more clearly.

Comment: The question is clearer now. Did I get right what you intended in my answer?

Comment: Just completely rewrote the description of classes and their inheritance, it should be clearer now. :)

Comment: Why don't you just store each type of `Sprite` in their own `List`? That's essentially what a `Map<Class,List>` would do anyway. Also, how many objects are we talking? Have you experienced speed issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mifeet seems to have literally answered your question, but I suspect you shouldn't be trying to do what you're proposing to do. Why not just have a master list of all objects that might collide, then filter it as needed using `instanceof`?

This is conceptually a lot easier than what you're proposing to do, and the [efficiency impact probably isn't that big.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103564/the-performance-impact-of-using-instanceof-in-java) (In general, you will probably hear or have heard the mantra: Don't try to optimize too early.)

To be honest, I'm not sure you realize that filtering for `EnemySprite` will get you all object instances of its subclasses as well.

```
public class CollisionChecker(){

   private List colliders;

   public CollisionChecker(){    
       colliders = new ArrayList<Object>();    
   }

   public void addCollider(Object o){
       colliders.add(o);
   }

   public List<EnemySprite> getEnemySprites(){
       List<EnemySprite> enemies = new ArrayList<EnemySprite>();
       for (Object o : colliders)
           if (o instanceof EnemySprite)
               enemies.add((EnemySprite)o);
       return enemies;        
   }     
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right! I had no idea that instanceof() works for subclasses, so I'll use something similar to your answer - going through a single list of all objects and narrowing the results is just more than sufficient for my needs. Thanks!

Comment: For a more generalized solution, [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37174482/5743988)

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways how to approach this. One would be, e.g., to generate strings like `ParentClass1:ChildClass2:ChildClass1:` for every object and use them as a key to a `TreeMap` or [`Trie`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/623892/2032064) which you would then traverse.

Here is a simpler solution, though. The following class contains a map from class to all objects implementing it. The only trick is adding an object to all buckets where it belongs:

```
public class HierarchyMap {
    private final Map<Class<?>, List<Object>> map = new HashMap<>();

    public void add(Object o) {
        Class<?> clazz = o.getClass();
        while (clazz != Object.class) {
            List<Object> list = map.computeIfAbsent(clazz, c -> new ArrayList<>());
            list.add(o);
            clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
        }
    }

    public List<Object> getByClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        return map.get(clazz);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class A { public String toString() { return "A"; } }
public class B extends  A{ public String toString() { return "B"; } }
public class C extends  B { public String toString() { return "C"; } }
// ...
HierarchyMap hierarchyMap = new HierarchyMap();
hierarchyMap.add(new A());
hierarchyMap.add(new B());
hierarchyMap.add(new C());
System.out.println(hierarchyMap.getByClass(B.class)); 
// prints [B, C]
```

Comment: I would update the map while iterating instead of constructing a throwaway list. Also, if you want a lighter map and faster writes (albeit with slower reads), you can map an object only by its own class and traverse the hierarchy in `getByClass()`.

Comment: I totally agree with the first point. The second depends on the usage pattern so it's up to @Brikowski to decide.

Comment: As for my specific problem, I have decided to use an easier method, but your algorithm answers my question very well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you're storing the objects in a `List<Object>`, call `Class#isInstance()` on each element, adding them to another `List` if `isInstance()` returns `true`.

```
List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();

public <T> List<T> getObjects(Class<T> desiredClass) {
    List<T> desiredObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object o : objects)
        if (desiredClass.isInstance(o))
            desiredObjects.add((T)o);
    return desiredObjects;
}

getObjects(EnemySprite.class); // call it like this
```

Comment: *...that allows me to **efficiently** get all objects...*

Comment: @shmosel It depends on how many objects we're talking. 1000s? Yes

Comment: If it's a minimal number of objects, I don't think OP would have mentioned efficiency as a concern.

Comment: Alternatively, you can just use `o.getClass() == desiredClass`, but that won't allow a check for inheritance (though it would be faster).

Comment: I didn't actually know that instanceof() would work for subclasses, so I didn't realize your answer is right until now. But thanks!

Comment: Great! Keep this implementation in mind if you would like it to be reusable for other classes. It uses generics (notice the `T`) in order to generalize the operation for any class that you might want to search for.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want collision detection, then I would add them to a static collection in the ancestor class. This would be the most efficient solution.

If you want to all descendants for a class you should check out the reflection APIs. Yes, they're said to be slow, but I have doubts that it matters enough for things that aren't computed for every frame. And for things that you need in every frame tree traversal would inefficient anyway. (@Miffet's suggestion of string comparison would probably be even slower than regular reflection.)